# duplicate git history for duplicate files

Tags: java, git, module, version-control, refactoring

Part of a refactoring task I need to split a project module (old-module) in 2-3 other modules (module1, module2, ...). However it is not a clean cut, some files I will duplicate in each new module. The project has a long Git history already.

**The question:** How can I duplicate Git managed files and keep their history at the same time? After I push the new modules I would like to do a git log on the duplicated files in the new modules and still see the old history of changes of the initial file.

Comment: Not sure if it's the best solution, but you can clone your repository, use `git-filter-branch` to remove everything you don't want (files and their history), and then move the files if needed.

Comment: I never used that before but the docs page is full of warning signs: "Please do not use this command if you do not know the full implications". Thanks, I'm looking into it